# utf8_encode() doesn't really work

Tags: php

I am having trouble with `utf8_encode()` function.

Here's an example

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $str = "Şşİğ";
    echo utf8_encode($str);
    ?>
```

the output i see is

> SsIg (third one is a capital i)

if i don't use `utf8_encode()` this is what i get

> ÅÅÄ°Ä

So, this doesn't really work for some languages. It only makes it a bit sense instead of making it right.

Thanks

Comment: theres probably an extra byte in there that cant be converted.  In which case utf-8 just ignores it.  Check the docs on that function, you should be able to customize what gets ignored or forced when something cant be converted to utf8

Comment: What's the encoding of the PHP file?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath its also UTF-8. Rooster, i'll try that thank you.

Comment: If it is utf8 why encode it to utf8? I can reproduce this behavior and taking out the utf8_encode resolves it. That function is for... `Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8`.

Comment: Interesting ... you should send `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` before any content though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the encoding of the string is already UTF8 (as opposed to ISO-8859-1(5)), [you need do nothing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php):

> utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

Actually, running `utf8_encode` on a string which is already UTF8 is bound to wreak some kind of havoc.

You say that the file encoding is UTF8, but what you get looks like ISO-8859. So I suspect you have something that's messing up with the encoding chain.

Verify the `Content-Type` header (**i.e. verify that the one you set is, indeed, the one that gets sent**), double check the file encoding, and the browser setting as well (it should be either UTF8 or autodetect).

Also, it is quite strange that you should get "SsIg" -- that is definitely *not* the expected behaviour of UTF8 encoding. It almost seems that *something* is trying to map your characters back into the ASCII set by mapping them to the most similar ASCII character. I'd therefore also check any proxies or caches or *anything* in the middle which is in position to manipulate the data sent by your script.

Comment: I checked and everything seems to be right. Weird part is, when i use `mb_detect_encoding($str, "auto")` on variables that i've created, it says they are already UTF-8. However, i see some weird stuff. Still couldn't understand why.

Comment: Okay i've fixed it. I was using EasyPhp for windows and i went for a re-install. Double checked everything you said and its working now. Besides, fixinig my problem, you gave some pretty good information here. Thank you so much.